# Convert.Double(string) works wrong

Tags: c#, .net, string, double

I try to read some weight values from a mettler toledo weighing machine via serial port. When i convert the string i get from serial port to double it puts the dot to wrong place. It converts 144.95 to 14495.0. How can i convert this string to correct double value ?

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, 
    // and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
    this.BeginInvoke(
        new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), 
        new object[] { sender, e });
    return;
}
string pattern = @"\s.(\d+\.\d{2})(\sg\r\n(S\sS\s.)?)?$";
string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
if (mc.Count > 0)
{
    if (tartim)
    {
        double weight = Convert.ToDouble(mc[0].Groups[1].Value); //Wrong conversion
        if (weight > weightLowerLimit && weight < weightUpperLimit)
        {
            MoveToNextSlot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(mc[0].Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: What is the value of `mc[0].Groups[1].Value` exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: I think problem is with your regex pattern.

Comment: Ulugbek Umirovs answer is right. Thanks